# How do I add cover art to an .aiff on OSX from the commandline

Tags: command-line

How do I add cover art to an .aif file on OSX from the commandline.

With ffmpeg this seems fairly easy for mp3 and other formats but i need aiff's with cover art.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under OS X, I've used [Kid3](http://kid3.sourceforge.net) to add cover art to AIFF files, from both the GUI and CLI with the latter in both direct and interactive modes. The CLI version is not for the faint of heart and you must read the documentation  [The Kid3 Handbook (English version)](http://kid3.sourceforge.net/kid3_en.html) to use the CLI, especially the [CLI examples section](http://kid3.sourceforge.net/kid3_en.html#kid3-cli-examples) as it shows something that's not shown elsewhere in the documentation or output of the internal help file of `kid3-cli`.

Which is the use of single quotes around the *commands* being used, e.g.:

```
kid3-cli -c 'select "/path/to/filename.aiff"' -c 'set picture:"/path/to/coverart.jpg" "Picture Description"' -c 'save'
```

Note that the example above is basic syntax for just setting cover art and `/path/to/` can be omitted if everything is in the *working directory* and `"Picture Description"` can be `""` if no description is wanted, but it has to be supplied one way or the other in this use case.

The `kid3-cli` executable is within the kid3.app application bundle, e.g. `/Applications/kid3.app/Contents/MacOS/kid3-cli` and to make it easier to use, you might want to set an *alias* for it in your `bash` profile file or set a *symlink* for it to a location that is within the `PATH` variable.

Example for your `bash` profile file:

```
alias kid3-cli='/Applications/kid3.app/Contents/MacOS/kid3-cli'
```

Example to create a symlink from Terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/kid3.app/Contents/MacOS/kid3-cli /usr/local/bin/kid3-cli
```

Then from the command line you could use: `kid3-cli ...`